# Vector of structs with vector of integer

Tags: c++, vector, struct, argv

my task to do is to create a little programm in C++, which load logs and text files and separate their parameters with their values.

The structure of input file is like:

```
#CURRENT_OPTIMIZED_BVH_NODES
210023
#CURRENT_OPTIMIZED_BVH_COST
118.856
#CURRENT_OPTIMIZED_BVH_COST_RATIO
1
#ANIMATION_TIME
0.0321091
#REFIT_TIME
0.0411972
#UPDATE_TIME
0.000135373
#UPDATE_TIME_SUM
0.000135373
#BUILD_TIME_SUM
0.000135373
#UPDATE_REFIT_RATIO
0.00328597
...
```

And my task is to make output, that will appear in cmd when user write name of some parameter.
Like this:

```
#CURRENT_OPTIMIZED_BVH_NODES
210023
210024
210065
210047
265400
....
```

My program looks like this right now. I have two problems - I have no idea how to work with vectors, but i need them because of dynamic arrays (Nobody know how many different parameter are in the file and also how many values single parameter has) and then how to use argc, argv for my output. 
I have found many advises, but nowhere was a practise, that i could use for my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct ParStruct
{
    string name;
    vector<double> value;
    double average;
    double min;
    double max;
    double median;

}; 

void WriteParameter(ParStruct Parameter, int SizeOfValueArr)
{
    cout << Parameter.name << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SizeOfValueArr; i++){
        cout << Parameter.value[i] << endl;;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    vector <ParStruct> Parameter;
    Parameter.push_back(ParStruct());
    Parameter[0].value.push_back(double());



    string s = argv[0];
    argv[1];

    int LogNumber, LineNumber = 1, optionnumber;
    ifstream LogFile;

    double ParValue;

    string MemoryLog, options, fileline;

    string LogFilePath;

    cout << "Path: ";
    getline(cin, LogFilePath);

    LogFile.open(LogFilePath);

    while (LogFile.good()){

        while ((getline(LogFile, fileline)) && !(LogFile.eof())) {

            if (fileline[0] == '#'){ //Parameter
                MemoryLog = fileline;

                for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.size(); i++) {
                    if ((fileline != Parameter[i].name) && Parameter[i].name.size() < 2)    {
                        Parameter[i].name = fileline;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Parameter.push_back(ParStruct());
                        Parameter[i].name = fileline;
                    }

                }

            }
            else {
                istringstream Number(fileline);
                Number >> ParValue;

                for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.size(); i++) {
                    if (Parameter[i].name == MemoryLog) {
                        for (int m = 0; m < Parameter[i].value.size(); m++) {
                            if (Parameter[i].value[m] <= 0) {
                                Parameter[i].value[m] = ParValue;
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.size(); i++){
        WriteParameter(Parameter[i], Parameter[i].value.size());

    }

    LogFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the general structure is wrong. you need to create a `map` (check C++ lib documentation) with keys as parameter names, and values as vectors of read values. BTW you push_back something while iterating on the items  (`Parameter.push_back(ParStruct())`). Sounds wrong.

Comment: What are you asking? Why have you tagged this [tag:c]?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Well, yes it sounds wrong, but it works perfectly. I just always need to creat a new array with NULL values and exactly this  (Parameter.push_back(ParStruct())) do it. Dont ask me why, Im a beginner :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it, here is my whole program and it works perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct ParStruct
{
    string name;
    vector<double> value;
    double average;
    double min;
    double max;
    double median;

};

double average(ParStruct Parameter)
{
    double average = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.value.size(); i++){
        average += Parameter.value[i];

    }

    average = (average / Parameter.value.size());

    return average; 
};

double min(ParStruct Parameter){

    double min = Parameter.value[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.value.size(); i++) {
        if (Parameter.value[i] <= min) {
            min = Parameter.value[i];
        }

    }


    return min;
};

double max(ParStruct Parameter){

    double max = Parameter.value[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.value.size(); i++) {
        if (Parameter.value[i] >= max) {
            max = Parameter.value[i];
        }

    }


    return max;
};

double Median(ParStruct Parameter)
{
        int middle = (Parameter.value.size() / 2);

        double median;

        //sort numbers
        sort(Parameter.value.begin(), Parameter.value.end());

        //

        if (Parameter.value.size() % 2) {
            median = Parameter.value[middle];
        }
        else {
            median = (Parameter.value[middle] + Parameter.value[middle + 1]) / 2;
        }

        return median;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    vector <ParStruct> Parameter;
    Parameter.push_back(ParStruct());

    int LogNumber;
    ifstream LogFile;

    double ParValue;

    string MemoryLog, fileline;

    string LogFilePath;

    bool writtenName; 

    //

    // Check the number of parameters
    if (argc < 3) {
        // Tell the user how to run the program
        cerr << "Usage: <" << argv[0] << "> <Path to the file> <Parameter Name>" << endl;
        /* "Usage messages" are a conventional way of telling the user
        * how to run a program if they enter the command incorrectly.
        */
        return 1;
    }

    // Print the user's name:

    LogFile.open(argv[1]);

    if (!(LogFile.is_open())){

        cout << argv[1] << " File opening FAILED";
    }

    while (LogFile.good()) {

        while ((getline(LogFile, fileline)) && !(LogFile.eof())) {

            if (fileline[0] == '#'){ //Parameter
                MemoryLog = fileline;

                for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.size(); i++) {
                    if ((fileline != Parameter[i].name) && Parameter[i].name.size() < 2)    {
                        Parameter[i].name = fileline;
                        writtenName = true;
                    }
                    else if (fileline == Parameter[i].name)
                        break;

                }
                if (writtenName){
                    Parameter.push_back(ParStruct());
                    writtenName = false;
                }
            }
            else { //Number
                istringstream Number(fileline);
                Number >> ParValue;

                for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.size(); i++) {
                    if (Parameter[i].name == MemoryLog) {
                        Parameter[i].value.push_back(ParValue);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.size() - 1; i++) {
        Parameter[i].average = average(Parameter[i]);
        Parameter[i].min = min(Parameter[i]);
        Parameter[i].max = max(Parameter[i]);
        Parameter[i].median = Median(Parameter[i]);
        //TO DO ANOTHER CALC
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < Parameter.size(); i++) {
        if (Parameter[i].name == argv[2]) {
            cout << "Parameter: " << Parameter[i].name << endl;
            cout << "AVERAGE: " << Parameter[i].average << endl;
            cout << "MIN: " << Parameter[i].min << endl;
            cout << "MAX: " << Parameter[i].max << endl;
            cout << "MEDIAN: " << Parameter[i].median << endl;
            cout << "SIZE: " << Parameter[i].value.size() << endl;
            for (int n = 0; n < Parameter[i].value.size(); n++)
            {
                cout << Parameter[i].value[n] << endl;
            }


        }

    }

    LogFile.close();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```